# Regex-alternative match is a substring of another match

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I am cleaning data using regex and there are matches that are a substring of the other alternative matches, and when you extract the matches, the one with the substring **DIMM** is extracted but the one that is intended to be extracted from the cell. **SO-DIMM** is extracted as intended except for **SODIMM**.

I have tried

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(B75, "(?:SO-DIMM)|(?:SODIMM)|(?:DIMM)")
```

but I checked the cells containing **SODIMM** but **DIMM** was extracted.

Comment: Maybe you want `"\b(?:SO-?)?DIMM\b"`?

Comment: If you could provide what you've tried, and some sample strings which you're matching, along with what you expect the matches to do at regex101.com like this: https://regex101.com/r/SVXRwG/1  it might help

Comment: @s2Milleniums I posted an answer below with explanation, demo and graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
\b(?:SO-?)?DIMM\b
```

The regex matches

- `\b` -  a word boundary
- `(?:SO-?)?` - an optional sequence of `SO` and then an optional `-`
- `DIMM` - `DIMM`
- `\b` -  a word boundary.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2q01qt/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5Cb(%3F%3ASO-%3F)%3FDIMM%5Cb):

[image]

Comment: From the question: `but I checked the cells containing SODIMM but DIMM was extracted.` Why doesn't OP's original regex not work?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(B75, "(?:SO-DIMM)"), 
                 REGEXEXTRACT(B75, "(?:SODIMM)")),
                 REGEXEXTRACT(B75, "(?:DIMM)"))
```